# Show project detail using react-redux-firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

[image]

I want to see the detail of my project but I cannot get the value to show. From `console.log`, I see that `project` is `undefined`.  This means that the props do not bring any content.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux';

const DetailProject = (props) => {
    // console.log(props)
    const { project } = props
    
    if (project) {
        return (
            <div className="container section project-details">
                <div className="card z-depth-0">
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <span className="card-title">{ project.title }</span>
                        <p>{ project.content }</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-action gret lighten-4 grey-text">
                        <div>Post by { project.authorFirstname }</div>
                        <div>Create at { project.createAt }</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="container center">
                <p>Project loading...</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
   
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    
    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const projects = state.firestore.ordered.projects;
    const project = projects ? projects[id] : null;
    return {
        project: project
    }
}
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'projects' }
    ])
)(DetailProject);
```

[Complete Code on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-hermann-lfwzv)

The cards on the left are my projects.  Clicking on one should show the details page for that project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the firestore data incorrectly in `mapStateToProps`.

`state.firestore.ordered.projects` is an `array` of the projects in the correct order.  You are using the `id` as the array index so you will not find a match.

You *can* access a project by `id`, but you need to be looking in `state.firestore.data.projects` instead.  This is the dictionary of projects keyed by `id`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const projects = state.firestore.data.projects || {}

    return {
        project: projects[id]
    }
}
```

This will get you the correct `project` in props.

Now you have a new error to fix in the component.  `project.createAt` is an `object` so you need to format it into a date `string`.